# Node.js mongoose REST aggregate

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to get detail stats from my website's counter rest api. The database has the following structure. please, I am new to node.

```
 bear.IP = req.body.IP;
 bear.CountryName = req.body.CountryName;
 bear.CountryCode = req.body.CountryCode;
 bear.ISP = req.body.ISP;
 bear.City = req.body.City;
 bear.Os = req.body.Os;
 bear.Date = req.body.Date;
```

POST requests for every pageload to REST. 
I can get total views count by -

```
 router.use('/counter/total', function (req, res) {
     Bear.distinct('_id').count().exec(function (err, viewcount) {
         res.json(viewcount);
     });
 });
```

I want to get is ({Distinct(CountryName):viewcount}) - or ({Distinct(OS):viewcount}) such similar aggregate . But I can't able to make it.

required Output is like this -

```
[{
    "United Kingdom": "121345"
}, {
    "Australia": "18645"
}, {
    "Myanmar": "297"
}, {
    "United States": "17212"
}, ...
```

How can I solve this problem. kindly help me please. Thanks.

small Sample DB -

```
  [{"_id":"597c802a33dc398272000001","Os":"Windows","FingerPrint":"3185454076","City":"Yangon","ISP":"Telenor Myanmar","CountryCode":"MM","CountryName":"Myanmar [Burma]","IP":"37.111.1.237","__v":0},{"_id":"597c802a33dc398272000002","Os":"Windows","FingerPrint":"1711566246","City":"Kajang","ISP":"TM Net","CountryCode":"MY","CountryName":"Malaysia","IP":"60.48.94.211","__v":0},{"_id":"597c802e33dc398272000003","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"3338867125","City":"Yangon","ISP":"Tech Solutions","CountryCode":"MM","CountryName":"Myanmar [Burma]","IP":"74.50.208.220","__v":0},{"_id":"597c802e33dc398272000004","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"4170065776","City":"Kuala Lumpur","ISP":"U Mobile Sdn Bhd","CountryCode":"MY","CountryName":"Malaysia","IP":"123.136.106.229","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803033dc398272000005","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"1276175308","City":"Kuala Lumpur","ISP":"TM Net","CountryCode":"MY","CountryName":"Malaysia","IP":"175.140.188.42","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803033dc398272000006","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"585184694","City":"Bangkok","ISP":"True Internet","CountryCode":"TH","CountryName":"Thailand","IP":"171.99.162.51","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803033dc398272000007","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"4149392815","City":"Shah Alam (Seksyen 11)","ISP":"DiGi Telecommunications Sdn. Bhd.","CountryCode":"MY","CountryName":"Malaysia","IP":"115.164.88.199","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803333dc398272000008","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"2143955121","City":"Kuala Lumpur","ISP":"Maxis Communications","CountryCode":"MY","CountryName":"Malaysia","IP":"113.210.66.130","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803333dc398272000009","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"2914318643","City":"Yangon","ISP":"Telenor Myanmar","CountryCode":"MM","CountryName":"Myanmar [Burma]","IP":"37.111.15.178","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803533dc39827200000a","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"1819736779","City":"Puchong Batu Dua Belas","ISP":"TM Net","CountryCode":"MY","CountryName":"Malaysia","IP":"124.13.138.153","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803533dc39827200000b","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"1178799827","City":"Yangon","ISP":"Myanma Posts and Telecommunications","CountryCode":"MM","CountryName":"Myanmar [Burma]","IP":"103.52.14.108","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803733dc39827200000c","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"3933020417","City":"Kuala Lumpur","ISP":"U Mobile Sdn Bhd","CountryCode":"MY","CountryName":"Malaysia","IP":"123.136.112.220","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803833dc39827200000d","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"4079283873","City":"Loikaw","ISP":"Myanma Posts and Telecommunications","CountryCode":"MM","CountryName":"Myanmar [Burma]","IP":"103.52.12.167","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803933dc39827200000e","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"3722986014","City":"Bangkok","ISP":"3BB Broadband","CountryCode":"TH","CountryName":"Thailand","IP":"27.130.160.142","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803a33dc39827200000f","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"2595883208","City":"Yangon","ISP":"Fortune International","CountryCode":"MM","CountryName":"Myanmar [Burma]","IP":"103.215.194.7","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803b33dc398272000010","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"3844048617","City":"Parit Raja","ISP":"Ytl Communications Sdn Bhd","CountryCode":"MY","CountryName":"Malaysia","IP":"183.78.126.125","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803b33dc398272000011","Os":"Windows","FingerPrint":"2163751345","City":"Singapore","ISP":"MobileOne","CountryCode":"SG","CountryName":"Singapore","IP":"138.75.196.239","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803e33dc398272000012","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"475903491","City":"Songkhla","ISP":"3BB Broadband","CountryCode":"TH","CountryName":"Thailand","IP":"171.7.236.10","__v":0},{"_id":"597c803f33dc398272000013","Os":"Android","FingerPrint":"999220323","City":"Yangon","ISP":"Myanma Posts and Telecommunications","CountryCode":"MM","CountryName":"Myanmar [Burma]","IP":"45.112.176.80","__v":0}]
```

Comment: Could you show your sample database looks like first, please?

Comment: @WildanS.Nahar, Yes, I added to question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [aggregation example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in-group-stage), maybe try

```
router.get('/counter/total', function (req, res) {
    Bear.aggregate([
        { 
            $group: { 
                _id: "$CountryName"
                viewcount: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    ], function (err, bears) {
        console.log(err, bears);
        // remap the results
        var viewcounts = bears.map(function (bear) {
            // using ES6 to compute property name
            return { [bear._id]: bear.viewcount };
        });
        console.log(viewcounts);
    });
});
```

Comment: Great solution for me. Thanks.